# How to use document field value as argument for $slice?

Tags: mongodb

Consider these two documents:

```
{ currentIndex: 1, elements: [4, 5, 6] }
{ currentIndex: 2, elements: [4, 5, 6] }
```

How do I get this result, sorted by the `elements` element at index `currentIndex`?

```
{ currentIndex: 1, elements: [5] }
{ currentIndex: 2, elements: [6] }
```

I read about $slice[1] but it seems that arguments to it can't be dynamic. All the examples use actual integers as arguments for it and not a string that identifies a value in the document to use as an index.

[1] http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/

Answer (score 1):

If currentIndex is unique or you can add unique field to your Collection then you can use mapreduce:

```
db.coll.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(this.currentIndex, { currentIndex: this.currentIndex, elementAtCurrentIndex: this.elements[this.currentIndex]});
    }, function(key, values) {
        return values[0];
    }, {
        out: "result"
    }
)

db.result.find({}, {"value.currentIndex":1, "value.elementAtCurrentIndex":1, _id:0}).sort({"value.elementAtCurrentIndex":1})
```

Answer (score 0):

For relatively small data sets, you could use the cursor method **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** to iterate the cursor and access the documents, use JavaScript's native **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** method to get the desired array and save the results to another collection, as in the following example:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function (doc){
    doc.elements = doc.elements.splice(doc.currentIndex, 1);
    db.result.save(doc);
})
```

Check the demo below

```js
var cur = [
    { currentIndex: 1, elements: [4, 5, 6] },
    { currentIndex: 2, elements: [4, 5, 6] }
];
var results = [];
cur.forEach(function (doc){
    doc.elements = doc.elements.splice(doc.currentIndex, 1);        
    results.push(doc);
});

pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```